# Consuming my promise inside my Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

In my angular service I have a method that makes an AJAX call and returns a Promise (I am not using Observable in this case).  The method looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class InnerGridService {
...
    private results: Object[];

    constructor(private logService: LogService, private http: Http) {
      ...
      this.results = [];
    }
    loadAccountList() {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                    res => {
                        this.results = res.json().results;
                        resolve();
                    },
                    msg => {
                        reject(msg);
                    }
                );
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

I am trying to consume this promise object in my component by assigning it to a variable like so:

```
export class ClientListRowDetailsComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

    promiseRowData: any[];
    constructor(private innergridService: InnerGridService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       ...
       // my JSON array from promise
       this.promiseRowData = this.innergridService.loadAccountListPromise();
    }
}
```

Now in my component I have an object `[object Promise]`, but I wonder what is the proper way to consume this object inside of my Angular component? If it was an observable I would subscribe to it by doing something like:

```
this.responseObject$.subscribe(( response: ResponseObject) => {...}
```

I wonder what is the best way of using the Promise in my component.

Comment: Why do you have to use a promise? It is highly recommended that you use Observables instead with Angular.

Comment: Yes, I know, but for circumstances I have no control over, I need to use a Promise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `res.json().results` as a parameter when calling `resolve`, like this: `resolve(res.json().results);`.

Then when you get the promise, call `.then()` on it to get the value.

```
this.innergridService.loadAccountList()
    .then(result => this.promiseRowData = result);
```

Or you can leverage `async/await` syntax:

```
async loadAccountList() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
            .toPromise()
            .then(
                res => {
                    this.results = res.json().results;
                    resolve(res.json().results);
                },
                msg => {
                    reject(msg);
                }
            );
    });

}
```

And in your component:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    ...
    // my JSON array from promise
    this.promiseRowData = await this.innergridService.loadAccountList();
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting, but just a clarification...the code `this.innergridService.loadAccountList()`
    `.then(result => this.promiseRowData = result);` . That is in my component?  I though I was calling it with `this.promiseRowData = await this.innergridService.loadAccountList();`

Comment: Yes that is in component. Those two are basically equal, just different syntax (async/await is basically syntactic sugar for working with functions that return promises, so your code looks more like classic synchronous one, which is more readable).

Comment: Oh i see.  I guess you would recommend calling it with keyword await because its easier to read?  Rather than classical .then?

Comment: Yes, if you write new code, its better to use async/await syntax.